# Docker Debian and python base58

Tags: python, docker

I have this Docker image

```
FROM debian

RUN  apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y \
    autoconf \
    build-essential \
    bc \
    curl \
    git \
    wget \
    jq \
    libssl-dev \
    libtool \
    net-tools \
    openssl \
    python3-pip \
    pkg-config \
    procps \
    sed \
    vim \
    xxd \
    ca-certificates \
    gnupg \
    dc \
    zsh \
    && apt clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

   RUN pip install base58
```

and I get this error since 2 week

> ```
>     > [ 3/11] RUN pip install base58:
> #0 2.868 error: externally-managed-environment
> #0 2.868
> #0 2.868 × This environment is externally managed
> #0 2.868 ╰─> To install Python packages system-wide, try apt install
> #0 2.868     python3-xyz, where xyz is the package you are trying to
> #0 2.868     install.
> #0 2.868
> #0 2.868     If you wish to install a non-Debian-packaged Python package,
> #0 2.868     create a virtual environment using python3 -m venv path/to/venv.
> #0 2.868     Then use path/to/venv/bin/python and path/to/venv/bin/pip. Make
> #0 2.868     sure you have python3-full installed.
> #0 2.868
> #0 2.868     If you wish to install a non-Debian packaged Python application,
> #0 2.868     it may be easiest to use pipx install xyz, which will manage a
> #0 2.868     virtual environment for you. Make sure you have pipx installed.
> #0 2.868
> #0 2.868     See /usr/share/doc/python3.11/README.venv for more information.
> #0 2.868
> #0 2.868 note: If you believe this is a mistake, please contact your Python installation or OS distribution provider. You can override
> ```
>
> this, at the risk of breaking your Python installation or OS, by
> passing --break-system-packages.
> #0 2.868 hint: See PEP 668 for the detailed specification.
> ------
> failed to solve: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c pip install base58]: exit code: 1

I have this error since two weeks, and I don't understand how can I resolve it. I'm trying to create very slim image without lucky

Comment: Have you tried _any_ of the resolution suggestions from that error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good practice when creating docker images is to set a tag to the image you are using to avoid breaking changes from version to version like so: `FROM debian:12-slim`. Otherwise its going to use the `latest` tag and download whatever is latest.

The message is very clear.

> To install Python packages system-wide, try apt install python3-xyz, where xyz is the package you are trying to install.

If you want it system-wide you are going to need to install it with apt instead of pip, `apt install python3-base58`

Or use a virtual environment